# Timeout to keep or reset settings when configuring displays

Tags: ubuntu, gnome, configuration, display

I'm using Ubuntu 18.04 on my Lenovo W540, and I want to connect three external displays to it through the "Ultra Dock" docking station, and not use the build-in display. According to the manual one display has to connect through VGA, the second through DVI or DP (my display don't have a DVI port, so it must be DP), and the third through HDMI or DP. Using VGA+DP+HDMI works, however the display connected through HDMI keeps flickering every 10 seconds or so. Instead of the HDMI cable I can also use a Mini DP cable and connect it directly to the laptop, that works fine, is however annoying if I take the laptop off the docking station.

I'd like to try using VGA+DP+DP, however then I have this problem: I can configure the settings, then apply them. After a couple of seconds all three displays are connected and I can move my mouse across all three. However the box with the question "do you want to keep these display settings [Keep] [Revert]" seems to take more than 15 seconds to display, so after 15 seconds it automatically reverts, and THEN shows the box, making it pointless at that moment...

With all other connections the box takes a long time as well, but usually appears a seconds or two before it would revert, so I just got enough time to hit "Keep". It seems to be faster if I add one display after another, not enabling all three displays at once, but even that doesn't help with VGA+DP+DP.

Is there a way to increase the timeout of this box, or if need to be disable it completely?

Comment: Were you able to solve this issue? Currently facing the same problem on a Ubuntu 22.

Comment: @Steven Thiel nope sorry. I kept connecting the third display directly to the laptop until I got a new one, where I didn't have that problem anymore.

Comment: Also a possibility. Thank you nevertheless for getting back to me!

Comment: Having the same problem (pop_os 22.04). I think that we can just see the confirmationbox because the settings have already returned to the previous settings and the box is just 'lagging'. The timing seems like too much of a coincidence to me.

Answer (score 3):

I am having a similar issue on Ubuntu 22.04 while using a docking station to connect to 3 monitors. I have not solved the problem completly, but I have found a few tricks to attenuate the problem which might make it possible to fix the situation.

I have noticed that the more applications running/opened, the longer it takes for the box to appear. So I usually close all my programs (almost as if I just started the computer). This is usually enough in my case to make it work.

I have also noticed that if you make smaller changes in the display configuration, the box takes less time to show up. Example: I want to switch place monitor 2 and 3, and I want to make monitor 2 primary display instead of 1. In that case, I would start by switching monitor 2 and 3 then apply settings. If that worked, then I would continue with making monitor 2 primary display and then applying settings again.

If nothing works, try rebooting computer and changing display settings as soon as you can. This way, you usually have less application running when you just fresh rebooted.

Comment: Upvoted. This worked for me on Linux Ubuntu 22.04 running on a Dell Precision 5570 laptop with a dual 4k 60 Hz DP 1.4 adapter plugged in: `try rebooting computer and changing display settings as soon as you can.` See my question here: [Ask Ubuntu: Increase timeout when modifying display settings](https://askubuntu.com/q/1501187/327339)